# Fixing a site that when accessed responds with "Site can't be reached - Connection reset", then loads fine

Tags: wordpress

I'm having an issue where initially when you go to my Wordpress site it errors out in Chrome, responding with "`The site can't be reached - Connection reset.`" and then a couple seconds later refreshes automatically and loads perfectly.

If I try to access the site again, it loads fine until a few days have passed. I can't tell if this is a browser issue (caching of some sort seems to be involved), a host issue (HostGator), or something involving my `.htaccess` / `database` / or `wp-config.php`.

Any idea what would cause this and how to resolve this?

Comment: This is a network issue. Essentially, your network is not able to connect out to the Internet quick enough and the first set of requests are not being responded to. I get this a lot when my network driver gets stupid when the laptop goes to sleep or is busy such as after waking up the screen saver. This can also happen under a load - particularly while pinging the dog snot out of the hard drives. While the LAN works okay, apparently, getting out to the WAN requires a bit more time (1 second or so). I would suggest this is not a website issue. Cheers!!

Comment: @Closetnoc - Your answer seems plausible for sure, but I don't think it's the case here as this happens for multiple people (across the country) testing this site. Also, testing via GTMetrix results in "An error occurred fetching the page: Status read failed: Connection reset by peer." And no other site I'm accessing is doing this, so it makes me continue to think that it's site specific, although I clearly can't prove it. :)

Comment: Yes. *Connection reset by peer* can indicate another problem. This tells me that there was no response from the server. If this is happening to multiple people across networks, you are absolutely right. I have seen problems with off-the-shelf network cards used by web hosts. I used to be one of the original registered ISPs and a web host. Back in the day, if a web host built their own servers from clones, then issues were a real option. It could simply be a bad network card or even a bad router port. Or even a bad cable. But I doubt is has anything to do with software or your site per se'.

Comment: Is your server's IP address changing?!

Comment: @w3dk IP is remaining the same as far as I can tell. Pinging the site results in connection timing out, and giving the same IP address that HostGator has given me - so they appear the same. Even when I use FileZilla to FTP, it initially fails, waits for retry, logs in, but fails to retrieve the directory listing due to a time out.

Comment: How is the domain pointed at HostGator? Is HostGator managing the DNS (ie. the domains NAMESERVERS point to HostGator - are these correct?) or is the DNS managed elsewhere and you have `A` records pointing at the HostGator server? If you examine the DNS zone for your domain does it all look OK? Shared or dedicated server? If shared, find another site that is hosted on the same IP and check that?

Comment: @w3dk / closetnoc - DNS is managed elsewhere and points to HostGator's name servers. However, I think you guys nailed it. I found the other sites on the same shared server as my site - they all have the exact problem I have. I suppose my only solution is making HostGator move my server (they're in denial anything could ever be wrong) or switch?

Comment: "DNS is managed elsewhere and points to HostGator's name servers" - That would seem to be a contradiction... you can't have the DNS managed elsewhere **and** point to HostGator's name servers?? Curious that other sites on the server also appear to exhibit the same behaviour ("for multiple people [and services] (across the country)"?) yet HostGator is still denying anything is wrong?!

Comment: @w3dk I stumbled over the term/phrase "dns management." I meant to say that my registrar is GoDaddy, which name servers are directed to HostGator, which does my actual DNS management there. I did notice my website has both the www AND non-www versions of my domain when I looked to see who else was on the IP, which seemed strange. Either way, HostGator it's been about 5 hours since I told them about it, and none of the sites are timing out anymore. They may have denied it being them, checked it, realized the issue and resolved it. Or maybe just a coincidence. You saved me hours though-thank u!

Comment: I am glad you got it. Remember that most web hosts maximize profits by minifying competence. ;-) That is one reason why I left the clown college.